How to Test Combine Code with .receive(on:) Without Injecting Schedulers?
I am using the Combine framework in my iOS project, and I am writing unit tests for my code. However, I encounter problems when testing code that uses schedulers. Here's an example of a function I want to test:
func getData() {
    state = .loading
    someAsyncPublisher()
        .receive(on: .main) // This line makes testing difficult.
        .sink(
            receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    self?.state = .failed(error)
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
            },
            receiveValue: { [weak self] data in
                self?.state = .loaded(data)
            }
        )
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

Currently, I see two options for dealing with this:
Use custom delays in tests:
I can add manual delays in my test/mock environment to ensure enough time for the Combine pipeline to execute. However, this solution is unreliable. Sometimes the tests pass locally but fail in CI/cloud environments. Increasing delays helps, but it feels like a hack and makes my tests slow.
Inject the scheduler into the system under test (SUT):
This is a clean solution because I can inject a TestScheduler or an ImmediateScheduler for testing. However, this approach increases the complexity of my code since I need to modify the function signatures or introduce additional abstractions for scheduler injection.
I am wondering:
Are there any other solutions to test such Combine code without relying on delays or injecting schedulers?
How can I simplify my tests while maintaining reliability?
I’d appreciate any suggestions or best practices for testing Combine code, especially when .receive(on:) introduces challenges.

I think you could use Singleton Scheduler and override its value base on enviroment

I use Swift Testing. Publisher can be anything, property or function result.

The bottom line is that you want your test function to not return until the asynchronous work is done. Historically, in XCTest, we would frequently use an expectation, but we can also can await a result. In the Swift Testing framework, we have no expectations, so we must simply await asynchronously retrieved results.
In a comment, you suggest you are looking for a generalized solution, where the “Publisher can be anything, property or function result.” Unfortunately, there is no generalized solution.

If you just want to test a function that returns an Publisher, the process is pretty simple; simply await the first value in the Publisher’s values sequence:
@Test
func testSomeAsyncPublisher() async throws {
    let foo = await Foo()

    let value = await foo.someAsyncPublisher()
        .values
        .first(where: { _ in true })

    #expect(value == expectedValue)
}


If you want to test getData (including the sink that updates the state), you need to figure out what to await.
If, for example, that was a @Published property of an ObservableObject, we would await that property’s values sequence:
@Test
func testGetData() async throws {
    let foo = await Foo()

    var iterator = await foo.$state.values.makeAsyncIterator()

    #expect(await iterator.next() == .notLoading)

    await foo.getData()

    #expect(await iterator.next() == .loading)
    #expect(await iterator.next() == .loaded(expectedValue))
}

Admittedly, I have simplified this example and made State conform to Equatable. But I didn't want to get too lost in the if/guard case code for all these states, but rather wanted to focus on the await of the values: The idea is to hook into whatever mechanism your app uses to know when the asynchronous work is done, and await that.



But, I share your apprehension about adding fixed delays in tests. Having timeouts in expectations or asynchronous sequences is bad enough, but adding a fixed delay is even worse. Definitely an anti-pattern.
One could theoretically could poll, but that is code-smell, and only marginally better than a fixed delay. But if you wanted to poll, you could do something like:
@Test
func testGetDataPollingIsBadIdea() async throws {
    let foo = await Foo()

    await foo.getData()

    let task = Task {
        let start = ContinuousClock.now
        while start.duration(to: .now) < .seconds(3) {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(100))

            switch await foo.state {
            case .failed(let error):
                throw error
            case .loaded(let value):
                #expect(value == expectedValue)
                return
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        Issue.record("Timed out waiting for data")
    }

    try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        try await task.value
    } onCancel: {
        task.cancel()
    }
}


By the way, when writing async tests, you might want to make sure to supply a timeLimit. See Limiting the running time of tests. Personally, I find this time limit (measured in minutes!) sufficiently annoying that I write my own timeout logic, but it is probably beyond the scope of this question.
